Existence of a bijection between $Hom_F(E,\bar{F})$ and $Hom_{\sigma(F)}(\sigma(E),\bar{F)}$.
I need to prove the following:
Let $\bar{F}$ be an algebraic closure of $F$ and $E/F$ be an algebraic extension. Let $\sigma \in Hom_F(E,\bar{F})$ be a non-zero embedding. Prove that there exists a bijection between  $Hom_F(E,\bar{F})$ and $Hom_{\sigma(F)}(\sigma(E),\bar{F})$.
I have an idea that I could use following Proposition:
Let $L/E,E/F$ be algebraic extensions, and $\bar{F}/F$ be an algebraic closure. The map $Hom_F(L, \bar{F}) \to H om_F(E, \bar{F})$, $\sigma \mapsto \sigma|_E $ is surjective.
Can anyone give me some hint, how to continue?
Thanks a lot.

Try conjugation by sigma

Since for any morphism $E\to\bar F$ over $F$ you want a morphism $\sigma(E)\to\bar F$ over $\sigma(F)$ is would recommend to precompose with $\sigma^{-1}$ so to say. Since $\sigma$ is a morphism of fields it is injective, hence the restricted $\sigma\colon E\to \sigma(E)$ is bijective. So the inverse gives you a good map $\sigma(E) \xrightarrow{\sigma^{-1}} E \xrightarrow{\theta} \bar F$ for every $\theta\colon E\to \bar F$ by precomposition with $\sigma^{-1}$.
